# Why do i get this ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.300\xa0%'?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

| Taux moyen pondéré |
| --- |
| 2,300% |
| 2,330% |
| 3,134 % |
| .... |

```
df['Taux moyen pondéré']= df["Taux moyen pondéré"].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Comment: `%` is not allowed. Don't know why you also have `\xa`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just replacing the commas (`,`) with dots (`.`) You have to remove the percentage (`%`) sign also before trying to convert it to a float. A string cannot be converted to a float when it has special characters like the `%` sign inside it.

Comment: How can i remove the % sign ?

Comment: ***df['Taux moyen pondéré']= df["Taux moyen pondéré"].str.replace("%", "")***

Comment: Thank you.It works

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote! :)